# Is selenium a specific language oriented (like Java)?

Tags: selenium

I am new to Selenium. After searching for tutorials and references, I found most of them are based on Java, specially the `WebDriver` part. I know JavaScript, will that be useful with Selenium?

Comment: Yes. [A simple search for "selenium" and "Javascript"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=selenium+javascript&t=ffab&ia=qa) should answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) (the part that lets you automate a web browser) is [available for Javascript as an NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver).

Here is their example of use.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#programming-languages

It supports massive range of languages including Javascript.